# HTTPService Issue returning GeoCode results to DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am creating a Flex3 app to return some results from the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html#XML).

I am using the HTTPService Events sample from [TourDeFlex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/tourdeflex/web/) as a reference guide to mimic.

For now, I have hardcoded the response from Google to use this XML response:
[maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false)

Network Monitor suggests that I am getting a valid response from the XML, but I imagine I have not referenced it correctly for populating my DataGrid?

I have screencasted the issue [here](http://www.screencast.com/t/yUjHVgffXJmX).

Here is a stripped down version of my code:

```
private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
        results = event.result.GeocodeResponse.result;
        }

        private function faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
        Alert.show(event.fault.faultDetail, "Error");
        }           

    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:HTTPService id="srv" 
            url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&amp;sensor=false"
        result="resultHandler(event)"
            fault="faultHandler(event)"/>

<mx:TitleWindow title="Find" showCloseButton="true" close="closeMe();"
            styleName="formPanel" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
            width="400" height="200">

    <mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{results}" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="type" headerText="Address"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>

  <mx:Button label="Go" height="20" styleName="buttonGo" click="srv.send()"/>
</mx:TitleWindow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a look at the xml. It could be that the first occurance of **type** is at a top level, but from then on **type** is an element of **address_component**.

Maybe try **address_component.type** as the datafield of the DataGridColumn? Or set the dataprovider to results.address_component?

**Edit Update**

Because its reading XML, maybe set `resultFormat="e4x"` inside the `<HttpService ..>` tag, and have an XMLListCollection awaiting the result:

```
<mx:XMLListCollection id="xc" source="{srv.lastResult.result}"/>

<mx:DataGrid id="dg" dataProvider="{xc}">
```

In debug mode, set a watch on XC to make sure its being populated

Comment: I think the DataProvider (results) is the Array delcared earlier (not in code) - 
[Bindable] private var results:ArrayCollection;

Comment: I also do not think I should be drilling down to the address_component level. 
The items I need from the response are lon/lat, as well as the formatted_address.  From how I read the XML, both of these fall outside the address_component?

Comment: The line im talking about is <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="type" headerText="Address"/>. Why is 'type' the datafile?

Comment: I thought as a test, id try and pull off <type>street_address</type> from that XML response?

Comment: Updated my answer, its based on the fact that its all XML, and saves using ArrayCollection (because I think XMLListCollection should be used)